# Historical changes to same origin policy with XMLHttpRequest requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote some javascript about four years ago with an XMLHttpRequest request that looked something like:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/script.php?arg=val&sid=' + Math.random(),true) ;
```

where example.com was the same domain.  This does not work now, so I changed it to:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'script.php?arg=val&sid=' + Math.random(),true) ;
```

and everything works fine on all the major browsers, as expected.

My question is this: Did the same origin policy for Chrome and Firefox change in the past four years in such a way to make this XMLHttpRequest need fixing?  From what I remember is used to work, but obviously I can't go back in time to test it, and I can't see any documentation online that indicates a change of same origin policy.  Apologies if this is off topic, I just want to understand how this change of behaviour happened.  A simple "Yes, this changed" or "No, it never changed, and this should never have worked in the first place." will do.

Comment: ahh but you can go back in time... http://www.oldversion.com/windows/mozilla-firefox/

as far as SOP it hasn't changed much since it was introduced in Netscape Navigator 2.0 however there was a change sometime within the last I want to say 1.5 years that locked down chrome even further... firefox has likely adopted that as well in recent versions... though i cant point you to a specific release number for either

Comment: Thanks for a speedy answer!  I'll take a look at the old version of Firefox and get a definitive answer :)

Comment: Note that `/script.php` and `script.php` are different.  What happens when it "does not work?"  What is the specific error that you get?

Comment: @jfriend00: Change that comment to an answer. I'm 99.9% convinced that that is what's actually happening

Comment: @slebetman - I made it into an answer.

Comment: Ah, I should have specified "not work".  The AJAX request is sent successfully, but the responseText was an empty string.  After the fix it was a snippet of HTML.  The paths to script.php were the same in both instances, I just didn't bother including all the directories in the example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Same origin must match the domain exactly, the protocol (e.g. `http` or `https` must match) and the port (if specified). My guess is that your page either switched to `https` or started using a custom port?

For example, from `https://www.example.com/index.html`, you could not do an ajax call to `http://www.example.com/script.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but in this instance I was use the http protocol for both.  Although thinking about it, it's possible one of the domains was missing the leading "www".